# The confusion usage of atlas and maximal atlas

Tags: manifolds

I'm studying Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds*. In p.60 he said
[image]

Given a smooth manifold $M=(\underline{M},\Phi_{\text{maxi}})$, it is understood by people that there exist a maximal atlas $\Phi_{\text{maxi}})$ of that underlying set $\underline{M}$. However, what does the "atlas" refer to in (ii)? Is it belongs to the origin maximal atlas (given immediately when he said "Let $M$ be a manifold ..."), or could be any atlas even outside the original maximal atlas? How to tell from the context?

Comment: Another viewpoint: is you can cover $M$ by a subset of charts of the maximal atlas $(U,\phi)$ s.t. the compositions $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ are smooth, then the same is true for *all* the charts of the maximal atlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't required that the atlas in (ii) be maximal, but a such atlas can be extended to a maximal atlas preserving the property, namely the maximal atlas defining the smooth structure.

Comment: Is the atlas in (ii) require to be $C^{\infty}$ equivalent with the original maximal atlas? (To be concrete, it is possible for a topological space $X$ to have several different maximal atlases. When giving a smooth manifold, it is known that a maximal atlas is specified. Then is the atlas mentioned in (ii) belongs to it?)

Comment: @Eric, yes. See my other comment.